# ThreeJS material side visibility updates

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have the side hidden when looking at it from the back which is correct and what i want however i cant find a way to know that its not visible from the renderer or the camera.

[image]

[image]

`new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    map: new,
    THREE.TextureLoader().load('image.jpg'),
       side: THREE.FrontSide
    });`

If i log the child within the render i see visibility is 'true' even though its not rendered (image 2).

Is there a way i can tell with THREE if a targeted geometry face is being displayed?

Thanks.

Comment: Just out of curiousity, why do you want to know if a face is displayed? What's the purpose?

Comment: There will be more faces to the model which i want to hide based on that single planes visibility.

Answer (score 0):

The fact your object (or part of it) is visible or not from a different angle depends on the `side` property of the material. On your example, only the front facing fragments will be visible (`side : THREE.FrontSide`);

If your goal is to keep track of whether the object, or part of it, should be showing at any given time from a given angle, there are multiple ways for you to do it.

One solution could be to simply raycast that face / region and check for intersection. I haven't tested it in a while but non visible face should not return an intersection.

[Here's a little documentation just in case](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/Raycaster)

And a quote from the docs :

> Note that for meshes, faces must be pointed towards the origin of the ray in order to be detected; intersections of the ray passing through the back of a face will not be detected. To raycast against both faces of an object, you'll want to set the material's side property to THREE.DoubleSide.